# scrollable overlay plugin and IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, github, overlay

I want to use the GitHub plugin Luxiyalu's scrollable overlay and the official demo of this plugin doesn't work with IE9. we can read this message error on the consol :

SCRIPT5007: Unable to get the property value "toggle": null object or undefined.

**ABOUT THIS FUNCTION:**

```
function toggleOverlay () { 
var overlay = document.querySelector("div"); 
overlay.classList.toggle('hide-overlaycookies');
```

HERE IS THE DEMO

http://www.luxiyalu.com/playground/overlay/

Comment: `classList` is not supported in IE9. In IEs it was introduced in [version 10](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh968262(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Ok and there is any solution to make it work on IE9, I wanted to use the balise 
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" > but nothing changes

Comment: yes...shim is documented in mdn docs  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList

Comment: There's a [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList#JavaScript_shim_for_other_implementations). Notice, that setting `X-UA-Compatible` doesn't upgrade a browser.

Comment: and so there is any possibilities ? ;(

Comment: ??? You've received the shim link twice, doesn't the linked article fulfill your needs?

Comment: ah i didn't seen the shim link, sorry

Comment: So it works perfectly thank you, i've created a js file with all JavaScript shim for other implementations code. but the error still exist, this is normal ?

Comment: I suppose it's not normal, maybe a place for a new question?